# Cannot create new record to the database; no error message

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to add new record to `trans_daily` table, however, the code snippet below executed on button click doesn't work.

**THE PROBLEMATIC CODE**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     try
     {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
        connection.Open();

        string strcom = "INSERT INTO trans_daily (retail_id, cust_name, quantity, " +
        "price, date, visibility, remarks_id) VALUES (@RetailID, @CustomerName, " +
        "@Quantity, @Price, @Date, @Visibility, @RemarksID)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strcom, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RetailID", ddRetailType.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", tbCustomer.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", float.Parse(tbQuantity.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", float.Parse(tbPrice.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Visibility", 1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RemarksID", 1);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch (Exception err)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
     }
  }
```

The following are the data types:

1. retail_id (int)
2. cust_name (varchar50)
3. quantity (float)
4. price (float)
5. date (datetime)
6. visibility (int)
7. remarks_id (int)

It's also worth to point out that *no* exception is being thrown.

What could have gone wrong?

---

**THE WORKING CODE** 
In a separate function, I was able to pull out data from `retail` table on form load and placed the pulled out data to a dropdown list.

```
    private void formAddTransaction_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
            conString = Properties.Settings.Default.MVGasConnectionString;
            objConnect.Sql = "SELECT * FROM retail";
            objConnect.connection_string = conString;
            ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

            MaxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            FillRetailTypes(conString);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }

    public void FillRetailTypes(string constring)
    {
        ddRetailType.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ddRetailType.ValueMember = "id";
        ddRetailType.DisplayMember = "type";
    }
```

Comment: It depends on what the exception message says. Let's dig into your exception and try figuring out what might have been gone wrong. If you can't just add it to your question and we'll help you out.

Comment: Except your error, did you close your connection?

Comment: Hi Tolga. After I clicked the button, there is no exception message that is displayed. I don't know if the code inside the function is even executed at all.

Comment: Hi @Jules. I didn't close my connection; no error message is displayed whatsoever.

Comment: @kulit how about setting a breakpoint and check if it is executed? ;)

Comment: Just one question... In the title you have mentioned MySQL, but the connection says it is "SQLConnection" Is it SQL or MySQL?

Comment: @nozzleman or surround with try catch

Comment: Hi @Anand, sorry for the confusion. I am using SQL. I updated my tags already.

Comment: What ExecuteNonQuery  is returning? 0 or 1?

Comment: @Jules I just tried using try-catch (`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`) but still no action after I click the button.

Comment: place a break point at the first line in Your click event handler and test, if this line is executed

Comment: Hi @Anand, ExecuteNonQuery returns 1.

Comment: That means one row is inserted. So, Let's rephrase your question "What do you mean by "click doesn't work""?

Comment: Have you check your database after you insert the record? If yes, maybe you want to "refresh" your `dropdown list` to see the result in your program

Comment: Put this code block in try catch and then check exception

Comment: @Anand I check the DB after every click of the button to check if any records has been added. I also tried refreshing it before viewing the content. Unfortunately, no data was recorded.

Comment: can you please modify your question and how us the complete (current) click event handler?

Comment: @Radinator I have modified my question by placing the whole click event function.

Comment: For me your code seems to be ok, verify you are accessing correct database as mention in connection string

Comment: Hi all. I tried using breakpoints and I found out that `DateTime.Now` did not return any value, so `@Date` has no value. `@Visibility` and `@RemarksID` did not also accept the value `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smartclientdata/2005/08/26/working-with-local-databases/), it seems like the problem is in the connection string.

Inside the project folder, 2 `.mdf` files were created: one is found at the root of the folder (let's call it `mdf_1`) and the other is inside the `bin\Debug` folder (let's call it `mdf_2`).

Now, taking a look inside the Visual Studio (VS) editor, there are 2 `.mdf` files shown: one under the Server Explorer, and another under the Solution Explorer. Not taking note of the location (from the properties section) of these `.mdf` files made me think these 2 `.mdf` files were the same. The thing is, the one under the Server Explorer is `mdf_1` while `mdf_2` is the one under the Solution Explorer.

VS has a behavior that copies `mdf_1` and overwrites `mdf_2` everytime the program is run (because by default, `.mdf` is set to *Copy always* `mdf_1` to `mdf_2`). My connection string was pointing to the `mdf_2` which explains why despite `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` command returns 1, my successfully inserted records are always erased because of the behavior VS has. And since it is `mdf_1` that is under Server Explorer, I could not verify the changes in DB. Simply put, I was making changes in `mdf_2` while trying to look for the changes in `mdf_1`.

So to avoid this, I modified my connection string by changing the relative path `|DataDirectory|` in the connection string to the absolute path of `mdf_1` so that no matter how often VS overwrites `mdf_2`, the changes I make during runtime in `mdf_1` aren't overwritten. This was, changes are also reflected in the Server Explorer (where I verify if changes were actually made).

---

**tl;dr** : I was updating the `.mdf` file under `bin\Debug` folder during runtime while physically looking for the updates in the `.mdf` file located in the root of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and you may find your error:

```
try
{
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        string strcom = "INSERT INTO trans_daily ([retail_id], [cust_name], [quantity], " +
    "[price], [date], [visibility], [remarks_id]) VALUES (@RetailID, @CustomerName, " +
    "@Quantity, @Price, @Date, @Visibility, @RemarksID)";

        cmd.CommandText = strcom;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RetailID", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameter["@RetailID"].Value = ddRetailType.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameter["@CustomerName"].Value = tbCustomer.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Float);
        cmd.Parameter["@Quantity"].Value = float.Parse(tbQuantity.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", SqlDbType.Float);
        cmd.Paramter["@Price"].Value = float.Parse(tbPrice.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameter["@Date"].Value = DateTime.Now;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Visibility", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameter["@Visibility"].Value = 1;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RemarksID", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameter["@RemarksID"].Value = 1;
        int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("You have inserted {0} rows", affectedRows);
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

This code will...

- ... automatically open and close your database connection and command object
- ... log the amount of affected rows in the database to the console
- ... log exception messages to the console. You may add a breakpoint to this line if you want to see the whole exception (if one occures)

Comment: since as the OP stated, no Exception is beeing thrown, the try-catch part doesn't add any value. Also, this is not the solution to the problem, its is just an attempt to "catch" the error without solving the issue

Comment: Currently, I don't want to fix anything with this code. I just try to find a way to get to know what's wrong with his code...

Comment: Therefore, I've written "Try this code and you may find your error:" and not "Use this, it's the solution"

Comment: Hi @Jules. Thanks for this. I tried inserting the code snippets to my code but it returned "You have have inserted 1 row" in the console. But nothing was really added to my table after viewing it. :(

Comment: @kulit, ```retail_id``` is your table's primary key, isn't it? Is it designed with autoincrement or do you choose the ID by your own?

Comment: @Jules Uhm, no. My primary key [in all tables] are all named `id`. It's set to automatically increment so I believe there's no need to include it in the code. :)

Comment: @kulit, fine. That's probably not the problem. I updated my code. Idk if this helps but it's worth a try

Comment: Hi @Jules. Thanks for the code. But as per checking through breakpoints, it seems like my parameters `@Date`, `@Visibility`, and `@RemarksID` cannot receive any values.

Comment: @kulit, one more try! ```date``` is a keyword in SQL. This may cause the problem. Those brackets will hopefully prevent it.

Comment: Hi @Jules. I tried your suggestion to encase keywords with square brackets , but still it didn't work :(

Comment: @kulit i'm slowly getting out of guesses... This is somehow driving me crazy.

Comment: @Jules I have tried performing an insert query directly in the SQL table and it was a success; thus there's nothing wrong with my insert syntax. I also tried setting all data types in DB to string for checking purposes but still insertion is not possible after the click event in the source code. :(

Comment: @kulit, is this the only code which accesses your DB in this project or do you've executed some SQL code somewhere else and it is working well?

Comment: @Jules I was able to pullout data from another table and assign the data to a dropdown list. I have updated my original post and placed the working function under _The Working Code_ section for reference.

Comment: @kulit, very strange. And there's still the problem that ```@Date```, ```@Visibility``` and ```@RemarksID``` aren't assigned to any value? I don't get why ```DateTime.Now``` doesn't return an acceptable value...

Comment: @Jules I temporarily changed everything in DB to `string` type just to see  it's not the data types that are causing the problem. I still couldn't insert new data. This is very strange because I have already followed different approach in inserting data to DB but nothing is working.